# passing part of a string as a parameter

Tags: java

im trying come up with a loop that will go through a spring and as soon as it gets to the % character, it will pass everything that comes after the % to the hexToInt function. this is what i came up with.

```
for(int x=0; x<temp.length(); x++)
    {
        if(temp.charAt(x)=='%')
        {
            newtemp = everthing after '%'
            hexToInt(newtemp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try with temp.substring();

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

Comment: And also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
newtemp = temp.substring(x+1);
```

Also, you should break after the `'%'` character is found. In fact, the whole snippet could be implemented like this (there's no need to write a loop for it!):

```
String newtemp = temp.substring(temp.indexOf('%')+1);
```

Comment: Thanks. can you also help me with the code to put '+' infront of the very last two characters in a string.

Comment: I have this but theres an error. red line under StringBuffer
word = StringBuffer(word).insert(word.length()-2, "+").toString();

Comment: It should be: `String word = new StringBuffer(word).insert(word.length()-2, "+").toString();`

Answer (score 1):

You can just take a substring of the original string from the first index of '%' to the end and accomplish the same thing:

```
int index = temp.indexOf('%') + 1;
String substring = temp.substring(index, temp.length());
```

If you need to break the string after the LAST instance of a '%' character to the end of the string (assuming there are more than one '%' character in the string) you can use the following:

```
int index = temp.lastIndexOf('%') + 1;
String substring = temp.substring(index, temp.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look at the String.split() method.

```
String str1 = "Some%String";

public String getString(){
    String temp[] = str1.split("%");
    return temp[1];
}
```

No loop is needed for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'contains' for comparison and substring() method

```
if(temp.contains('%')){
int index = temp.indexOf('%') + 1;
String substring = temp.substring(index, temp.length());
}
```

Comment: No need: he's comparing *characters* (note the single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to parse using a regexp instead of iterating the string char-by-char. 
Something like `(.*)%([0-9a-fA-F]+)` could also validate the hexadecimal token.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String toParse = "xxx%ff";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\%([0-9a-fA-F]+)").matcher(toParse);

    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Matched 1=" + m.group(1) + ", 2=" + Integer.parseInt(m.group(2), 16));
    }
}
```